# Using xargs in python to navigate data

Tags: python, xml, xpath

I'd like understand how to navigate more easily using xpath.
Suppose I have this structure:

```
<root>
 <main>
  <name>NAME1</name>
  <stats>
   <stats-category>CATEGORY1</stats-category>
   <statistics>
    <speed>100</speed>
    <max-speed>200</max-speed>
   </statistics>
  </stats>
  <stats>
   <stats-category>CATEGORY2</stats-category>
   <statistics>
    <speed>5</speed>
    <max-speed>10</max-speed>
   </statistics>
  </stats>
 </main>
 <main>
  <name>NAME2</name>
  <stats>
   <stats-category>CATEGORY1</stats-category>
   <statistics>
    <speed>0</speed>
    <max-speed>0</max-speed>
   </statistics>
  </stats>
  <stats>
   <stats-category>CATEGORY2</stats-category>
   <statistics>
    <speed>1</speed>
    <max-speed>5</max-speed>
   </statistics>
  </stats>
 </main>
</root>
```

Suppose we need to print  if max-speed > 0. In this example it would need to print:

```
NAME1 CATEGORY1 100 200
NAME1 CATEGORY2 5   10
NAME2 CATEGORY2 1   5
```

I have this working with something like this:

```
for name in (rpc_result.xpath('//main/name')):
 for stats in (rpc_result.xpath("//main[name='" + name.text + "']/stats/stats-category")):
  speed = (rpc_result.xpath("//main[name='" + name.text + "']/stats[stats-category='" + stats.text + "']/statistics/max-speed"))
```

In other words, I iterate again using previously found variable.
I know this isn't the right way, and I'm aware of using //, ../ in xargs, but I'm not sure how to use it in python syntax-wise.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to extract data for `main` nodes if `max-speed` is > 0 try

```
for name_node in (rpc_result.xpath('//name[.//max-speed > 0]')):
    name = name_node.xpath('./name')[0].text
    speed = name_node.xpath('.//speed')[0].text
    max_speed = name_node.xpath('.//max-speed')[0].text
```